# Getting this error OperatorError.OPERATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED @ operations[0] while using Google Adword API

Tags: python, api

I am getting an error while using ManagedCustomerService. I want to update the Account label and mutateLabel() Assigning label and Removing Label to Account both operations successfully done but getting OPERATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED while updating the Account label here is my full code.

```
from googleads import adwords
COSTOMER_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
LABEL_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage('googleads.yaml')
manage_customer_service = adwords_client.GetService('ManagedCustomerService', version='v201809')

operations = [
    {
        "operator": "SET",
        "operand": {
            "labelId": LABEL_ID,
            "customerId": COSTOMER_ID
        }
    }
]
try:
    response = manage_customer_service.mutateLabel(operations)
    print(response)
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception accrued:')
    print(e)
```